# Jquery ajax javascript functions fails randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

I have several functions executed in jQuery/ajax but I have random failures.

The first function always gets executed (in ajax). It calls the PHP code, adds data into database and afterwards the second function uses some of the returned data.

But the second is NOT executed at all! No response from *success* or *fail* or even *beforesend* methods in ajax.

If I put an `alert('something');` between these two functions, my 2nd function gets executed and if I don't it doesn't. Has anybody had this problem before?

**Code**

```
$("#send_new_arch_form").click(function(){
    if($("#archNewLocSet").val()=="0"){
        var name    = $("#nomArch").val();
        var fname = $("#prenomArch").val();
        var v1   = $("#rueArch").val();
        var v2 = $("#numArch").val();
        var v3 = $("#bteArch").val();
        var v4 = $("#locArch").val();
        var v5 = $("#telArch").val();
        var v6 = $("#emailArch").val();
        if((name == "")){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" * All fields Required").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(v5!='' && ((v5.length)<9)){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" Le num&eacute;ro de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone est invalide").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(v6!='' && ((validateEmail(v6))==false)){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" L'adresse e-mail est invalide").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else{
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").fadeOut();
            $.ajax({
                type    :'POST',
                url     :'./php/insertNewArch.php',
                data    :{  'name' : name,'fname' : fname,'rue' : v1,'numero' : v2, 'bte' : v3, 'loc' : v4,'tel' : v5,'email' : v6},
                error:function(response){
                    alert("<h3>Erreur lors de la cr\351ation...</h3>");
                },
                success:function(returnData){
                    alert("RETOUR : "+returnData);
                    $("#nomArch").val('');
                    $("#prenomArch").val('');
                    $("#rueArch").val('');
                    $("#numArch").val('');
                    $("#bteArch").val('');
                    $("#locArch").removeAttr('selected').filter("[value='']").attr('selected',true);
                    $("#telArch").val('');
                    $("#emailArch").val('');
                    $.fancybox.close();
                    $("#archListe").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : './php/getArchListe.php',
                        data : {
                            'query':'*',
                        },
                        error : function(){
                            alert('ERREUR MISE A JOUR DE LA LISTE');
                        },
                        success : function(response){
                            $('#archListe').append($('<option>',{
                                value : '',
                                text : 'Choisissez dans la liste'
                            }));
                            var myData = JSON.parse(response);
                            for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){
                                var id = myData[i].id;
                                var nom = myData[i].nom;
                                var prenom = myData[i].prenom;
                                var rue = myData[i].rue;
                                var numero = myData[i].num;
                                var boite = myData[i].bte;
                                var cp = myData[i].cp;
                                var loc = myData[i].loc;
                                if(rue!="" && numero!=""){
                                    rue = rue+", "+numero;
                                }
                                if(cp!="" && loc!=""){
                                    loc = "- "+cp+" "+loc;
                                }
                                var field = nom+" "+prenom+" ; "+rue+" "+boite+" "+loc;
                                $('#archListe').append($('<option>',{
                                    value : id,
                                    text : field
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }else{
        var name    = $("#nomArch").val();
        var fname = $("#prenomArch").val();
        var v1   = $("#rueArch").val();
        var v2 = $("#numArch").val();
        var v3 = $("#bteArch").val();
        var v4 = $("#paysLocArch").val();
        var v5 = $("#CPNewLocArch").val();
        var v6 = $("#nameNewLocArch").val();
        var v7 = $("#telArch").val();
        var v8 = $("#emailArch").val();
        if((name == "")){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" * Le nom est obligatoire!").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(v7!='' && ((v7.length)<9)){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" Le num&eacute;ro de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone est invalide").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(v8!='' && ((validateEmail(v8))==false)){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" L'adresse e-mail est invalide").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(($.trim(v5)!='') && ($.trim(v6)=='')){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" Impossible de cr&eacute;er une localit&eacute; sans lui donner de nom").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if(($.trim(v6)!='') && ($.trim(v5)=='')){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" Impossible de cr&eacute;er une localit&eacute; sans donner le code postal").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else if((($.trim(v5)!='')||($.trim(v6)!=''))&&(v4=='')){
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").html(" Impossible de cr&eacute;er une localit&eacute; sans choisir le pays").fadeIn("Slow").fadeOut(3000);
        }else{
            $(".errorNewArchMsg").fadeOut();
            $("#nomArch").val('');
            $("#prenomArch").val('');
            $("#rueArch").val('');
            $("#numArch").val('');
            $("#bteArch").val('');
            $("#paysLocArch").removeAttr('selected').filter("[value='']").attr('selected',true);
            $("#CPNewLocArch").val('');
            $("#nameNewLocArch").val('');
            $("#telArch").val('');
            $("#emailArch").val('');
            $.fancybox.close();
            var insertNewLoc = true;
            newLoc = false;
            if(($.trim(v5)=='')||($.trim(v6)=='')||($.trim(v4)=='')){
                insertNewLoc = false;
            }
            if(insertNewLoc == true){
                //alert("INSERT NEW LOC!!");
                newLoc = $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : './php/insertNewLoc.php',
                    data : {'pays':v4,'cp':v5,'localite':v6},
                    error : function(response){
                        alert("<h3>Erreur lors de la cr\351ation de la nouvelle localit\351</h3>");
                    },
                    success : function(returnData){
                        newLoc = returnData;
                        return newLoc;
                    }
                });
            }else{
                newLoc = v6;
            }
//IF I ADD ALERT('SOMETHING') HERE, THE .AJAX STATEMENT BELOW GETS EXECUTED, IF I DON'T ADD ANY ALERT, THE STATEMENT DOES NOT GET EXECUTED...
            $.ajax({
                type    :'POST',
                url     :'./php/insertNewArch.php',
                data    :{'name' : name,'fname' : fname,'rue' : v1,'numero' : v2, 'bte' : v3, 'loc' : newLoc,'tel' : v7,'email' : v8,'pays':v4},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    alert(newLoc);
                },
                error:function(response){
                    alert("<h3>Erreur lors de la cr\351ation...</h3>");
                },
                success:function(returnData){
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : './php/getArchListe.php',
                        data : {'query':'*'},
                        error : function(){
                            alert('ERREUR MISE A JOUR DE LA LISTE');
                        },
                        success : function(response){
                            $("#archListe").empty();
                            $('#archListe').append($('<option>',{
                                value : '',
                                text : 'Choisissez dans la liste'
                            }));
                            var myData = JSON.parse(response);
                            for(var i=0;i<myData.length;i++){
                                var id = myData[i].id;
                                var nom = myData[i].nom;
                                var prenom = myData[i].prenom;
                                var rue = myData[i].rue;
                                var numero = myData[i].num;
                                var boite = myData[i].bte;
                                var cp = myData[i].cp;
                                var loc = myData[i].loc;
                                if(rue!="" && numero!=""){
                                    rue = rue+", "+numero;
                                }
                                if(cp!="" && loc!=""){
                                    loc = "- "+cp+" "+loc;
                                }
                                var field = nom+" "+prenom+" ; "+rue+" "+boite+" "+loc;
                                $('#archListe').append($('<option>',{
                                    value : id,
                                    text : field
                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show us the functions

Comment: Show the code... may be you need to use async:false

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `async:false` to the `ajax` requests. I believe this will solve it since you said that by putting an `alert` it gets executed, since the `alert` will stop the rest of the flow and give time to the request to finish and let the second one get executed.

I would also recommend if you try to use deferred `jquery` objects to handle the success and failure cases of your responses. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/.This way you have much cleaner code and you don't end up chained `callbacks` one inside the other. Do the `async:false` first since I'm pretty sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: well... i tried to add "async:false" in my statements... but no effect... 
The fact is that : i have the part into if (insertNewLoc==true) when i get out of this part, if i add "alert("xx") just before the next .ajax part, it works fine... if i don't, it doesnt... can't get why... :(